# Is it possible to select specific values based on some condition?

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering if it's possible to select 'true' or 'false' from myTable based on if the given row matches some criteria.  So, for example if a user does or doesn't have a value in a column called phone_number I'd do...

```
select (**some magic here**) as has_phone_number from users;
```

and the result would be a bunch of 'true' or 'false'

TIA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF (phone_number != '', true, false) as has_phone_number
```

or even

```
phone_number != '' as has_phone_number
```

Comment: thanks... that's useful specifically for true/false, but I'm actually curious about supplying my own strings based on conditions... is that doable?

Comment: @Dr.Dredel: the `IF()` function returns whatever you passed as a 2nd or 3rd argument

Comment: Awesome, that's exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Use a case statement.

`SELECT CASE WHEN Phone IS NULL THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END AS has_phone_number FROM users;`

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  phone = '' as has_phone_number
from users
```